# How do you delete a mystery object?

Tags: modeling, objects

If you encounter an unexpected object in your blender file, how would you delete it?

For example, there is a mysterious egg shape object that I didn't notice until now because it was covered by a plane.

[image]

I can't select the object since it appears to be part of another object. 
I can't press <kbd>P</kbd> to try and separate the object by selection because blender warns 'no object selected'.

I have no idea where this shape came from, nor how to get rid of it.

[Blender File](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/460997/Blender/quarter-ring%20copy.blend)

Comment: Wait you can press P to separate?
So many hours were wasted because I didn't know that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's part of the ring object. The ring has a cube in it, which is being subsurfed and distorted by the modifiers, resulting in the "egg" object.

Select the ring (<kbd>[image: RMB] RMB</kbd>), enter edit mode (<kbd>↹ Tab</kbd>) and delete the cube at the top.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This egg shape object was the result of creating a cube while in edit mode. This caused it to inherit all the properties of the ring (sub surf modifier, mirror, curve deform).

To prevent this from happening again, make sure blender is in object mode whenever creating new objects (not edit mode).